# 2次元配列で表現した行列で列ごとの合計値を算出したい

Tags: ruby

（概念的には）以下のように、2次元配列で行列を表現したとします。

```
[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ..... [n-2,n-1,n] ]
```

これを

```
[(1+4+...+n-2), (2+5+...+n-1), (3+6+...+n)]
```

という具合に変換したいと思ってます。
`ruby`でスマートにやるとしたらどういう方法がありますでしょうか？

何とか再帰を使って解いてみましたが、ここまでやらなくても解ける方法があったら教えてもらえると嬉しいです。

```
def aaa(arr)
  if arr.size == 1
    arr
  elsif arr.size == 2
    bbb(arr[0],arr[1])
  else
    bbb(arr[0], aaa(arr[1..-1]))
  end
end

def bbb(arr1,arr2)
  ret = Array.new(arr1.size, 0)
  arr1.size.times{|n| ret[n] += arr1[n] + arr2[n]}
  ret
end

実行例：
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
aaa(a)
=> [22, 26, 30]
```

Comment: [(1+4+...+n-2), (2+5+...+n-1), (3+6+...+n)] の記述が間違っていたので書き直しました。

Comment: ruby言語リファレンスに記載のある、Array#tranposeの説明を参考にタイトルと本文を変更しました。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
a.transpose.map { |n| n.inject(:+) }
# => [22, 26, 30]
```

このような方法があります。いかがでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

`active_support`を使っていいのであれば `Enumerable#sum`が定義されてますので

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
a.transpose.map{|array| array.sum}
=> [22, 26, 30]
```

とできます。またブロックでそれぞれの要素の特定のメソッドの返り値を取りたい時は以下のような記述ができます。

```
a.transpose.map(&:sum)
=> [22, 26, 30]
```

Answer (score 1):

行（列）ベクトルの和と考えた場合です。

```
require 'matrix'

a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
p a.map {|x| Vector.elements(x)}.reduce {|accum,x| accum+x}.to_a
```

Answer (score 1):

安心してください。それ、NArray でできますよ。

配列を色々とゴニョゴニョしたいなら NArray が便利です。
以下のスライドで私は救われました。
[それ NArray でできるよ](https://speakerdeck.com/tmaedax/sore-narray-dedekiruyo)

```
require 'narray'
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
NArray.to_na(a).sum(1) # => [ 22, 26, 30 ]
```